# Vimeo api usage

Tags: vimeo

I have an application in which you can search for videos repeatedly. Do I need to new Vimeo everytime I call $vimeo->request?

```
$vimeo = new Vimeo(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN);

$vimeo->request('/videos?query=cars');
```

Comment: My money is on no, however can't you just test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to construct a new instance of the Vimeo object if you want to switch to different application id's secrets, or tokens.

Comment: I am using jquery ajax to get php file in which I have above mentioned code. How would I construct this call if I wanted only to construct a new instance once?

Comment: In PHP, you can not persist data between page loads, so you will need to construct the object on every page load.